# mod_rewrite seems to rewrite correctly but not displaying the correct page?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've got the following rewrite, that essentially rewrites the request to a wordpress plugin. It's not working as I expect, I don't get the correct page I'd like to see.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foobar/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/([0-9]+) /foobar/wordpress/wp-json/wp/posts/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The rewriteRule is working, as I can see on php:

```
[REDIRECT_URL] => /foobar/wordpress/wp-json/wp/posts/1
```

If I type this manually on the browser I get the correct page, in this case some json data, as this is a restful api.

When I try to access it using:

```
/foobar/api/1
```

it doesn't work, but displays a wordpress page saying  `Oops! That page can’t be found.`, if I debug it with php, I get the `[REDIRECT_URL] => /foobar/wordpress/wp-json/wp/posts/1`, this is the same URL I put in the browser manually and get the correct data.

It may be related but I have the following rewrite sitting on the wordpress directory

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foobar/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /foobar/wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Checking the logs, I can see the rewrite seems to look fine:

```
[Mon Apr 20 11:44:43.989509 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 8056:tid 1692] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 127.0.0.1:62897] 127.0.0.1 - - [magnolia/sid#445888][rid#2544ba8/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/foobar_site/] rewrite 'api/12' -> '/wordpress/wp-json/wp/posts/12'
```

Any tips on this issue about what can be causing this ?